# How to perform an Ajax call from a partial view. Asp.net MVC

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to perform an Ajax Call to get data from a form that is in a partial view, to a controller and get a response message back.

Ajax Call

```
$("#submitContactInfo").on("click", function () {
if ($('#contact-form').valid() === true) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SendEmailAsync", "Home")',
        type: "Post",
        data: {
            "name": Name.value,
            "lastName": LastName.value,
            "email": Mail.value,
            "phone": Mobile.value
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.value === "1") {
               ...
            }
            else {
               ...
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> SendEmailAsync(string name, string lastname, string email, string phone)
{
 var value = 0;
 ...     
  return Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I stumbled upon was that`@Scripts{}` does not work on partial views so I had to think of another way.

So I created an external file and named it 'custom.js' and referenced it on _Layout.chtml, below the:
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
...
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/custom.js")`

The second thing I noticed was that the url from the Ajax Call was not working because I was using Razor syntax in an external js file.

So I changed `url: '@Url.Action("SendEmailAsync", "Home")',` to `url: '/Home/SendEmailAsync',`

After that I was getting a 500 error, so I figured that by changing `type: "Post",` to `type: "Get",` and `dataType: "json",` to `dataType: "html",` and by adding `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` I was a little closer because I was getting a 404 error.

So I went to my Controller method and removed `[HTTPPOST]` and that was it.

Final Ajax Call:

```
$("#submitContactInfo").on("click", function () {
if ($('#contact-form').valid() === true) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/SendEmailAsync',
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            "name": Name.value,
            "lastName": LastName.value,
            "email": Mail.value,
            "phone": Mobile.value
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result === "1") {
               ...
            }
            else {
                  ...
            }               
        }
    });
  }
});
```

My Controller

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> SendEmailAsync(string name, string lastname, string email, string phone)
{
 var value = 0;
 ...     
  return Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you have a better solution or any remarks to make, feel free. I'm open to suggestions.